# Modal activity in android , prevent obscuring focused activity

Tags: android, windows, android-intent, android-activity

I have an application that is based on windows principles , and doesn't not follows the android way . . .

Do not ask why , it is just an requirement, I know that should not be done that way....

Here is the problem:

I have an application that fires two transparent activities , activity A and activity B.

if activity A is shown than if the activity B should be shown the is no problem, because the activity B will be over the activity A.
But if the transparent activity B is shown then if I fire an intent the activity A will be over the activity B ,.. :(, the business logic is that if B is shown then A should be also shown but behind the A. Then is the user dismiss the B , only then the A will be visible...

I hope I describe this good, I far as I know this is not possible, but I want to ask more experienced people

if there is possibility to start some activity that will not be covered by others activities

NOTE: I am talking for preventing activities only from  my application

Answer (score 0):

Make A search for a special command keyword in its Intent extras, If it is found, A also launches B from its `onCreate()`. So, to launch A, use simple intent of A; to launch B, put the special keyword in A's intent,  A will launch and also launch B.

Comment: A and B are started from service , not on some button or something..., your solution can not be implemented in my case. Also even I was able to put something special in the intent, this wont prevent A to take the focus and to be over B

Comment: How does your service start an activity ?

Comment: with an intent, the starting intents is not the problem, the problem is in the obscuring activities , I think you do not understand my problem :), but thanks for trying, however it is 10 people team could not solve this with the focus change, if please answer only if you are an expert :)